# Choose the best NLP parsers

Tags: parsing, nlp

I want to analyze a sentence using a context free grammar for NLP tasks.
I want to know which grammar parsers as Stanford Parser, Malt Parser,... would be great?

What are advantages and disadvantages about syntactic parsing and dependency parsing in those parsers?

How can they support library for programming languages as Java, PHP,...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend Stanford parser. It supports a powerful library for Java coding. You should check this site for more information about Stanford parser `http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/`. You also can run some demos at http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/